# How to remove transition of a border without affecting the width

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Whenever i toggle the class "dark_mode" the border color of the "width_animation" has a transition. Any ideas how could i remove the border transition without affecting the width transition? If i remove the transition of the class "width_animation" the width will go back to initial width after no hover and i don't want that, i want to be smooth.

```js
function darkMode() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark_mode");
}
```

```css
.dark_mode {
  background-color: #333;
}

.dark_mode .width_animation {
  border-color: red;
}

.product_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.width_animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.width_animation:hover {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="darkMode()">DARK MODE</button>

    <div class="product_container">
        <div class="width_animation">
            hover
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hint: read the [documentation for `transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and note that it is shorthand for several properties, including the properties that are transitioned.

Answer (score 1):

Add width to the transition. This will apply transition to the width only. Make sure to add it to both sections. See below.

```
.width_animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.width_animation:hover {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I've also heard that being as specific as possible about what attributes you want animated in `transition` can be very beneficial for performance, too.

Answer (score 0):

I might be reading the question wrong, but as I understand it you only want the border of the "hover" square to be red when Dark Mode is enabled, right?  Further, you only want the width transition to occur on-hover, and the two should be mutually exclusive.  Is that right?

```css
.width_animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dark_mode {
  background-color: #333;
}

/* The width_animation color transition will only apply when 
   the parent object has dark_mode enabled */
.dark_mode > .product_container > .width_animation {
  border-color: red;
}

.product_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.width_animation:hover {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you wanted to make it so that the "hover" square doesn't shrink after someone exits the hover animation (based on this part of your question `"the width will go back to initial width after no hover and i don't want that"`), you'll need to make `.width_animation:hover` a static style like below, and then use some javascript to add/remove the class on hover as desired.

```css
.width_animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dark_mode {
  background-color: #333;
}

/* The width_animation color transition will only apply when 
   the parent object has dark_mode enabled */
.dark_mode > .product_container > .width_animation {
  border-color: red;
}

.product_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.width_animation_hover {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
function darkMode() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark_mode");
}

var hover = document.getElementsByClassName("width_animation")[0];
hover.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
    if ( hover.classList.contains("width_animation_hover") ) {
    event.target.classList.remove("width_animation_hover");
  } else {
    event.target.classList.add("width_animation_hover");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.width_animation {
   -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, border 0.1s linear;
   transition: width 1s ease-in-out, border 0.1s linear;
}
```

And You have not to write transition into scope of :hover{}. **Because your going forward and backward transitions are the same.**